# Proving that ($W\bigoplus U)\cong(W\bigoplus V)\nRightarrow U\cong V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Here the symbol "$\cong$" means isomorphic and $V,U ,W$ are vector spaces.

I couldn't find a counterexample but my work so far has showed that such counterexample cannot be finite-dimensional and obviously $W\neq\{0\}$.I've worked with polynomial spaces but no good ideas so far. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

It's like $\infty+1=\infty+0$.

More specifically, it follows from $\lambda+\alpha=\lambda$ for cardinals $\alpha\le\lambda$ if $\lambda$ is infinite: we can take *any* infinite dimensional $W$ and *any* $U,V$ of dimension $\le \dim W$, then we will have
$$\dim(W\oplus U)=\dim W=\dim(W\oplus V)$$
hence $W\oplus U\cong W\oplus V$.

Even more specifically, let $W:=\Bbb R[x]$ as you suggest, let $U:=\{0\}$, $\ V:=\Bbb R$ and define the isomorphism $W\oplus V\to W$ by e.g. $(p,r)\mapsto r+x\cdot p$.

Comment: Delicous! Thank you!